# Java UML Diagrams: Use Case; Sequence; Class; and Activity

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case, sequence-diagram, activity-diagram

Does anyone know a tool/software the converts existing java code into Use Case; Sequence; Class; and Activity Diagrams?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to get Use Cases and Activity Diagrams from source code. They are abstractions that are "lost" into source code.

You could get the "Class" mode from Java source code, but you should build the diagrams yourself (usually by drag and drop). Getting automatically a full class diagram from a real Java project will result on a very complex unreadable diagram.

To get the class model from a Java source code available in a Git repository you could use [GenMyModel](https://www.genmymodel.com) ([doc](https://github.com/Axellience/customgen-documentation/blob/develop/reverse-gettingStarted.md))